# Как сделать так,чтобы человек для одного ответа могу задавать несколько вопросов?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Мне нужно, чтобы кроме "таблица умножения" бот так же реагировал на "табличка умножения"(к примеру),какой метод использовать, ибо в моем выдает ошибку

```
elif message.text == 'Таблица умножения', 'Табличка умножения':
            photo1 = open('3ebc0dfa867e344cf30d81409cfd7558.jpg', 'rb')
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elif message.text in ['Таблица умножения', 'Табличка умножения']:
```

Допустим так

Comment: спасибо,я о таком даже не шарил) а кстати, как сделать так, чтобы он видел разным регистром, к примеру Табличка умножения и табличка умножения

Comment: `message.text.lower()`

Comment: а куда вставить? в моем коде?

Comment: `elif message.text.lower() in ['таблица умножения', 'табличка умножения']:`